# symlink() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: laravel, symlink

i have uploaded a Laravel project on my host provider server successfully but the `symlink()` function is disabled which is required to access the storage files from the public folder, i have contacted them to enable it but they refused it and asked me to find an alternative way, is there any alternative way to access the storage contents from the public folder ? or what should i do ?

Comment: Don't use that hosting provider.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy unfortunately it's not available option.

Comment: could you not just move it?

Comment: @HeshamAbdAllah did you get any solutions.

Comment: @nasor Yup, i contacted the hosting service provider and they told me the function is disabled and can't be enabled.. I had to use thepure PHP functions like move().. When you save image with laravel (Storage::putFile() or whatever method you used )  the file is saved in ( storage/app) directory.. The symlink is disabled to let you read the files from ( public/storage) so all you need is to move the file to ( public/storage) directory by native move php function.. This is what i had done and it worked fine for me, it's the best solution you can get.